# Integration + Method of Moments

Tags: integration, moment-generating-functions, maximum-likelihood

So I am given a question whereby I am told that $(1+\theta)Y^\theta$ is my pdf and it has limits of $0\leq y \leq 1$ and I am asked to find the method of moments estimator for $\theta$ and also the MLE which I am pretty sure I can do myself just wanted to get some clarification on the MOM.

So, I know I have to integrate my pdf i.e. $E(x) = \int x\cdot f(x) dx$ with my limits. However, I am just unsure how I am suppose to integrate this out fully with the parameter of $\theta$ attached to $x$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, you are encouraged to learn LaTeX / MathJax typesetting at least long term as it helps clearly writing math expressions. Other than that you are encouraged to show any own tries you've made on the problem especially if the question looks like it could be homework in some course.

Comment: Keep the parameter fixed and integrate with respect to $y$ as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the random variable $Y$ has pdf $f(y)=(1+\theta)y^\theta$ on $0\leq y \leq 1$ for some parameter $\theta$, then keeping in mind this parameter is fixed,

$$\mathbb{E}(Y)=\int_0^1 y f(y) dy=\int_0^1 (1+\theta)y^{1+\theta} dy$$ 
Which can be evaluated by the power rule for integrals. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yep I am close to my answer I just wanted to clarify something because I know how to get to the answer now just not understanding it fully. So, I know I take the (1+θ) outside and then I am just left with the y^1+θ. When I integrate this, I thought since the constant is fixed it would go to y^2+θ /2  but the answer is y^2+θ/2+θ, so since the constant is fixed it also must go on the denominator when integrating ?

Comment: @XeroPhobous if there is something specific you are not understanding or something you want clarified, let me know and i can add to my answer...

Comment: just something specific with regards to the y^1+θ. Say if I was looking for the indefinite integral of y^3+θ that would be: y^4+θ/4+θ yes ?

Comment: @XeroPhobous yes, as long as $\theta$ isn't a function of $y$ and is treated as a fixed parameter, then the indefinite integral of $y^{n+\theta}$ is $\tfrac{y^{n+1+\theta}}{n+1+\theta} +C$  by the power rule for integrals (for each $n=1,2,3,\dotsc$

Comment: great ! thanks for the help ! :)

Comment: @XeroPhobous no problem :) if you wish to accept my answer there is a "checkmark" button to click.